# How to add call log using Open CTI

Tags: visualforce, tasks, opencti

I am new to salesforce development.

Can any one please let me know how to add call log using Opne CTI api, I mean is there any api that would add the call log ?

Comment: What do you mean under "call log", create task, record call or something else?

Comment: I mean I am going to build telephone app, once call is received I have to show call history like time etc. I have seen there is call a log option in salesforce. where I have to add my call details. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Open CTI API includes a `saveLog()` method:

> Saves or updates an object in Salesforce.

Have a look at the [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_cti/Content/sforce_api_cti_savelog.htm) that shows how to use it, this would allow you to create a new call log (probably as a Task). If you are creating your own Task then you'll want to link it to the call using the [`CallObject` field](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_task.htm) on task to contain the unique call ID.

Comment: Thank you Mark, 
I got your point. let me correct if i am wrong, you mean to say I have to create new task using saveLog and fields to save in save logs are WhoId, WhatId, callduration, OwnerId, calltype etc. right ?

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider marking the answer as accepted and/or upvoting. Thanks!

Comment: sure I will mark it as accepted. little more help will be appreciated once I will proceed coding, will post more quires .

Comment: Hi Mark.

documentation link was not accessible ? could you please check it ?

Comment: I've updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement web service, that would handle info, and invoke it when call finished.